# How to click on a link that gets hidden when I click outside a textbox input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box input in a form;
when I click it, a link appears next to it. When I click outside the text input box, the link gets hidden.

I have this code that changes style of the text box input field and hides the link:

```
$('#txtbox').blur(function(){
$('#txtbox').removeClass('active');
$('#txtbox').addClass('passive');
$('#link').hide();
});
```

I'd like to be able to click on the link, but when I click wherever outsite the text box, the link gets hidden.

How can the link remain visible when I click on it, but also to get hidden when I click outsite the textbox and when I don't click on the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(function(){
   $(document).click(function(){
      $('#link').hide();
   });
   $('#link').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      //Do other stuff on click of link here
   });
   $('#txtbox').blur(function(){
       $('#txtbox').removeClass('active').addClass('passive');
   }).focus(function(e){
       $('#txtbox').addClass('active').removeClass('passive');
       $('#link').show();
   }).click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YTCdz/)**

Comment: Excellent coding style. I'll try this now.

Comment: @Spec - Check my edited answer, fixed some of the issues and also added a demo link.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions to your problem

1:) use fadeout/slow hide

```
$('#link').fadeOut();
```

or

```
$('#link').hide('slow');
```

2:) use setTimeout()

```
setTimeout( function() { $('#link').hide('slow'); }, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could include an onChange function. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-change-trigger-and-onchange-event-in-input-box Besides here, a search for OnChange will give you many ideas.